# Haskell: Check for distinct value within three variables & count distinct variables

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to figure out how I could realise the following two functions.

1. Input 3 integers and check if two of them are equal (e.g. `1,2,2 -> true` and `1,2,3 -> false`)
2. Input 3 integers and count different values (e.g. `1,1,2 -> 2`)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What couldn't you figure out how to do?

Comment: Try to match all 5 cases explicitly with `if`/`else` (or guards if you prefer). Then simplify.

Comment: Alternatively, especially if your input is a list, `nub` is your friend.

Comment: Start with a clear problem statement. I'm guessing you mean "check if any two of the inputs are equal" and "count the number of distinct elements". Then write the type signatures you want. Then start trying to break down the problem into smaller parts and solve those

Answer (score 1):

sort and group elements and count the equivalence classes, which will give you the count of distinct elements

```
distinct = length . group . sort
```

use the above definition, if there are duplicates the number of distinct elements will be less than the number of elements.

```
dups = liftM2 (/=) length distinct
```

this is a fancier way of writing it simply

```
dups x = length x /= distinct x
```

Comment: (mind, `distinct` needs a type signature or else the monomorphism restriction monster will get you)